# Conditional expectation of random sums

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

A few days ago I came across the following problem:

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ and $W$ be random variables. 
Suppose 
 $W : \Omega \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ and 
$S_W := \sum_{i = 0}^W X_i \in L^1$. 
Determine whether or not 
the random sum $S_W$ satisfies 
\begin{equation}
(1)\hskip2cmE(S_W| W) =  \sum_{i = 0}^W E(X_i | W).
\end{equation}
I know this looks very similar to Wald's identity. However, since we can choose $W$ to be infinity outside of a set of probability $0$, I'm beginning to think that $(1)$ doesn't hold, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample. Is my intuition right, or does $(1)$ actually hold?. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The answer depends on what information you have about $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i$. Without any extra information $S_W$ is not even defined on that set $\{W=\infty\}$.

Comment: That's the thing. My issue here is that you assume that $S_W$ is in $L^1$. Doesn't that imply that $S_W$ is well define even when $W=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it is implicitly assumed that the series converges on teh set where $W=\infty$. You can prove (1) by writing $X_i$ as $X_i^{+}-X_i^{-}$. For non -negative $X_i$'s equation (1) is true, so it is true in general.

Comment: OK. thank u for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that you need to prove [two things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra), $\mathbb E [S_W|W]$ is such that

- It is $\sigma(W)$-measurable, this is quite trivial to show that $\sum_{i=0}^W \mathbb{E}[X_i\mid W]$ is a measurable function of $W$.
- For any $\sigma(W)$-measurable random variable $Y$, $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[S_W|W] Y] = \mathbb E[S_W Y]$.

Rewritting the last part you need to show that
$$\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^W \mathbb E[X_i|W] Y\right]=\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^W X_i Y\right]$$

This can sometimes be done as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^W \mathbb E[X_i|W] Y\right]&=\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^W \mathbb E[X_i Y|W]\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E} \left[\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=0}^W X_i Y\middle|W\right]\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{i=0}^W X_i Y\right]\\
\end{align*}
Using first the fact that $Y$ is $\sigma(W)$-measurable. On the last line it is just the tower property of conditional expectation. You can find all these properties [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)

For the second line, it is not always true for the infinite case and the answer is not fully known but a sufficient condition for it to hold is that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\middle|W=\infty\right]$ converges. So if $\mathbb P (W=\infty)\neq 0$, but you can prove the above convergence, or if $\mathbb P(W=\infty)=0$, then you are done. Otherwise there would be a bit more work for proving the equality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. First of all, notice that $S_W$ can be written as follows

\begin{equation}
S_W=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty X_j\mathbb{1}_{\{W\geq j\}}=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k X_j\mathbb{1}_{\{W\geq j\}}=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}S_W^k.
\end{equation}

Due to the linearity of the conditional expectation, we can assume that $X_j\geq0$ for all $j$. In this case, we deduce that $0\leq S_W^k\leq S_W\in L^1(\Omega)$, so $S_W^k\in L^1(\Omega)$ and $E(S_W^k|W)$ is defined. Then we can use the monotone convergence theorem to see that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E(S_W|W)&=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k E(X_j\mathbb{1}_{\{W\geq j\}}|W)\\
&=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \mathbb{1}_{\{W\geq j\}}E(X_j|W)\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{\{W\geq j\}}E(X_j|W)\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^W E(X_j|W).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Recall that we can take the indicator function out of the conditional expectation because is a bounded $\sigma(W)$-measurable function.